# how to update a table in laravel 5.2

Tags: php

when i click  my submit button it gives MethodNotAllowedHttpException line 218 my route seems to be Ok.

my blade is`id")}} " method = "post">

{{csrf_field()}}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <input type = 'text' name = 'name' value = '{{ $users->name}}'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = '2'>
            <input type = 'submit' value = "Update student" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`

MY ROUTE IS`Route::post('edit/{id}','StudUpdateController@edit');`

Controller

`public function show($id){
        $users =User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('stud_update',['users'=>$users]);
    }
    public function edit(Request $request,$id) {
        dd("welcome");
        $name = $request->input('name');
        DB::update('update users set name = ? where id = ?',[$name,$id]);
        echo "Record updated successfully.<br/>";
        echo '<a href = "/edit-records">Click Here</a> to go back.';
    }`

```
it doesn't diplay the welcome message
```

Answer (score 0):

i was to use Route::put() instead of route::post().it now works like a charm